# Why is a Python universal wheel is different when built on MACOS or Linux?

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-poetry

We are using GitHub repositories as binary repositories for wheel, so we have a GitHub Workflow that would verify if the committed wheel is stale with respect with the code.

To perform this test, we build the wheel in a Github Workflow and we compare it with the committed version. Surprisingly, this workflow fail even if the wheel is updated,
This Workflow fails even if the wheel is recent,

```
index 99be2e6..e47d595 100644
--- a/dist/pylib_template-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
+++ b/dist/pylib_template-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
@@ -16,9 +16,10 @@ G{
```

Why would `poetry build -f wheel` produce a different file on MacOS and Linux?

Comment: maybe it compare file time of creation, or wheel has some timestamp so even if you generate the same version it may have different value inside.

Comment: I tried it. It is not the case: locally the generated file is always identical